# CANCELED - TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert() method functionality

Tags: java, date, timeunit

Well I'm trying to get diference between times and I'm using `TimeUnit.XXX.convert()`.

Here's my piece of test code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = new Date();

        Date d2 = new Date();

try {
            d1 = sdf.parse("08/11/2015 10:00:00");
            d2 = sdf.parse("08/11/2015 14:30:00");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Duration in minutes: "  + TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(d2.getTime()-d1.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        System.out.println("Duration in hours: "    + TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(d2.getTime()-d1.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

The results were: 'Duration in minutes: 270' and 'Duration in hours: 4'.

[image]

But in fact the difference beteween 10:00:00 and 14:30:00 is 4,5 hours (decimal).

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How can you represent 4.5 hours with _units_ of hours?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes Tunaki, I didn't paid attention on return of the function. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

270 minutes if presented as hours are truncated to 4 hours.

Remember that the method [`convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))  returns a `long`, not a decimal value.

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

> Convert the given time duration in the given unit to this unit.
>   **Conversions from finer to coarser granularities truncate**, so lose
>   precision. For example converting 999 milliseconds to seconds results
>   in 0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's truncated... not rounded

Comment: @Lance... right truncated, I edit my answer and added the reference to the documentation highlighting it. Thanks